# Passing A Lambda into a method with MVCContrib

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, mvccontrib-grid

I have a method in my class that takes a bool and returns a string so that the user doesn't see true or false in the view. I am then trying to use this method in the MVCcontrib grid

```
public string BidStatusText(bool status)
    {

        if (status == true)
            return "Bid Confirmed";
        else if (status == false)
            return "Bid Denied";
        else
            return "Bid Pending";
    }
```

View

```
<%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model)  %>
<% Html.Grid(Model)

       .Columns( column => {
       column.For(x => x.BidText).Named("Bid Details").Sortable(false).Action(a => {%>
           <td>              
               <%= Html.ActionLink(a.BidText, "Details", new {id = a.BidID})%>
           </td>
                <% });
           column.For(x => x.Sector.SectorName).Named("Sector").Sortable(false);  
           column.For(x => x.Resource.ResourceName).Named("Resource Requested").Sortable(false);
           column.For(x => x.DateStart).Named("Start Date/Time").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");
           column.For(x => x.DateEnd).Named("End Date/Time").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}");

           column.For(x => x.BidStatusText(x.Status)).Sortable(false);


        }).RowStart((p,row)  => {     
             if (row.IsAlternate) { %>
                   <tr class="alt">
             <%  }  else  { %>
                 <tr>
             <% }
    })
    .Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["sort"])

    .Render(); %>
```

Error i get is

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type




public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions sort, int? page)
    {
        var bids = bidRepo.GetUpcomingBids();

        if (sort.Column != null)
            bids = bids.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
        ViewData["sort"] = sort;

        return View(bids.AsPagination(page ?? 1, 15));


    }
```

Comment: Could you post the entire grid definition? Your code seems correct and works for me.

Comment: is that third value of bool a joke?

Comment: @kikaimaru - True, false, or null. What's wrong with that?

Comment: if you want to store null in valuetype you have to make it bool? or Nullable<bool>

Comment: Actually thanks kikaimaru. You question led me to realise that i needed bool? status. Post it up as a quickie answer and i'll mark it as the correct answer